# Waiting until a file stops being modified

Tags: haskell, semaphore, inotify, stm, debouncing

I'm trying to use [hinotify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hinotify) and STM to make a simple concept:

- Block the thread of execution until the watched file *stops* being modified
- Continue once modifications stop, or their interval is larger than some time threshold (debounces)

Currently, I'm trying to use a TSem to get this working correctly, but I keep running into either of these problems:

- the thread doesn't block at all, and I end up removing the hinotify watcher before it even starts, throwing an exception
- the thread blocks indefinitely, causing STM to throw an exception
- the program prints 3 times (3 concurrent notifications), but only lasts for 1 second and not 10

The code I've written is below, and can be checked out [on github](https://github.com/athanclark/fileneglect) to see for yourself.

```
module Main where


import System.INotify
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TSem
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar
import Control.Monad (forM_)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  [file] <- getArgs


  -- make changes every 1/10th of a second for 10 seconds
  forkIO $ forM_ [0..100] $ \s -> do
    appendFile file $ show s
    threadDelay (second `div` 10)


  debouncer <- atomically $ newTSem 0
  notif <- initINotify
  expectation <- newTVarIO (0 :: Int)

  watcher <- addWatch notif [Modify] file $ \e -> do
    e' <- atomically $ do
      modifyTVar expectation (+1)
      readTVar expectation
    print e
    threadDelay second
    e'' <- readTVarIO expectation
    if e' == e''
    then atomically $ signalTSem debouncer
    else pure ()

  atomically $ waitTSem debouncer
  removeWatch watcher
  killINotify notif


second = 1000000
```

Do you see anything immediately wrong with what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be `STM`? You can achieve you goal with ordinary `MVar`s:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
  --resolver lts-7.9
  --install-ghc runghc
  --package hinotify
  --package stm
-}

import System.INotify
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar (newMVar, newEmptyMVar, readMVar, swapMVar, putMVar, takeMVar, modifyMVar_)
import Control.Monad (forM_, forever)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  [file] <- getArgs

  mainBlocker <- newEmptyMVar
  tickCounter <- newMVar 0

  -- make changes every 1/10th of a second for 10 seconds
  forkIO $ forM_ [0..100] $ \s -> do
    appendFile file $ show s
    threadDelay (second `div` 10)


  -- set up file watches
  notif <- initINotify
  watcher <- addWatch notif [Modify] file $ \e -> do
    swapMVar tickCounter 10
    print "file has been modified; reset ticks to 10"

  -- 'decreaser' thread
  forkIO $ forever $ do
    threadDelay second
    ticks <- readMVar tickCounter
    print $ "current ticks in decreaser thread: " ++ show ticks
    if ticks <= 0
       then putMVar mainBlocker ()
       else modifyMVar_ tickCounter (\v -> return (v-1))


  takeMVar mainBlocker
  print "exiting..."
  removeWatch watcher
  killINotify notif


second = 1000000
```

The idea is a 'tick' counter that gets set to 10 whenever the file has been modified. A separate thread tries to count down to 0 and, when it succeeds, releases the block of the main thread.

If you use `stack` you can execute the code as a script like this:

```
stack theCode.hs fileToBeWatched
```